# How to remove <p> like tags from xml using c#

Tags: c#, regex, xml

this is my xml,

```
<Description>
   <p><br>In house music panel.<br>Safe deposit box.<br>All modern and high quality installation and amenities.<br><br><br><b>All inclusive formula</b><br>Breakfast open buffet<br>Lunch open buffet<br>dinner open buffet<br>From 11.00 AM till 23.00 HRS<br>Water (Small Bottle)<br>Soft drinks<br>Local beer (Served by glass)<br>Local wine (Only during lunch and dinner)</p><p><br><b><b>The Program includes:</b><br></b>♦ 07 nights’ accommodation on board of MS b><br></b></p><p><b>Attraction - Combo Light Package</b><br>Visit to the east Bank, Karnak and Luxor temples, Visit the Temple shared by two gods Sobek and Haeroris in Kom Ombo afternoon, Morning visit to High dam, Phila   temple<br><b><br>Attraction - Combo Full Package Excursions</b><br>Visit to the East Bank, Karnak and Luxor temples, Visit the Temple shared by two gods Sobek and Haeroris in Kom Ombo afternoon, Visit Edfu Temple, Morning visit to High dam, Philae temple and unfinished obelisk, on return visits West bank, Hatsheput, Valley of the Kings, Memmon colossi Esna Temple<br><br><b>Attraction - Cruise Signature Program</b><br>Visit Dier-al-Madina + Habu Temple + Valley of the Nobles, Dendra Temple by bus + Temple of Hathor-Cript, Edfu OR Kom Ombo Temple (up to the customer) Kalabsha trip + Botanical Gardens + 01 hour felucca </p>
</Description>
```

Inside description tag it includes `<p>`, `<b>` tags. How can I remove these.

This is my code,

```
 var product = from a in cruiseDoc.Descendants("CruiseProduct")
                  select new CProducts
                  {
                      cId = a.Element("ID").Value,
                      cName = a.Element("Name").Value,
                      cDescription= a.Element("Description").Value// need for this
                  };
```

Comment: No idea what you mean. Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: You do know that's not valid XML?

Comment: this is my webservice and what I want is to display data inside the <Description> tag without <p><br> characters

Comment: Note that: html != xml

Comment: @anu - Yes, but it's not valid XML. You need to fix the source so that it produces valid XML before you ask your question.

Comment: No I didn't use it. how to use Regex with this parallely

Comment: @JacobWalker - There's no point asking what he's done if his input isn't valid XML. Once he has valid XML he can then try, but to do so before would be a waste of time.

Comment: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590)

Comment: Are you suppose to get html or xml from the webpage?  You may need to extract the xml from the html before you start parsing, or you may be going to the wrong webpage.

Comment: I'm getting xml from .ashx webservice and it returns string of xml web service

Comment: @anu - You're not getting XML from the webservice. It looks a lot like XML, but it's not **valid** XML. You need to fix that first.

Comment: @anu - Can you show the code from the `.ashx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for this...

```
var product = from a in cruiseDoc.Descendants("CruiseProduct")
                  select new CProducts
                  {
                      cId = a.Element("ID").Value,
                      cName = a.Element("Name").Value,
                      cDescription= Regex.Replace(a.Element("Description").Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to do

```
var regex=@"(?<=\<Description\>.*?)\<\/?(br|p)\>(?=.*?\<\/Description\>)";
var output=Regex.Replace(input,regex,"");
```